# Nsdictionay keyvalue coding error when trying to access the values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

```
{
  "gender" : "Male",
  "city" : "chenna",
  "instituteName" : "srm",
    "profileImage" : "ProfileImage",
    "dob" : "DOB",
     "emailAddress" : "saxasx",
  "isStudent" : "true",
 "studentIdValidity" : "Month2Year5",
"studentIdImage" : "IDImage",
 "name" : "xasx",
 "phoneNumber" : "9092256227"
}

     NSDictionary *dic ;
dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"fizzstudentjson"];

    NSLog(@"%@",dic);

NSString *strng = [dic objectForKey:@"city"];
NSLog(@"%@",strng);
```

Access dictonary values in nsstring when I am trying to my app is crashing 
that's code I have written help me out

Comment: What show you these NSLogs? Or can you attach crash log?

Comment: for dic log I am getting the above dictionary  string it is saying the it's not keyveluecoding when I am using valueforKey

Comment: @user5276912 what is {
  "gender" : "Male",
.....
} in your snippet? it's a log when debug?

Comment: Where you are setting the value for key?

Comment: check the city is available or not in your userdefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Log about data it's maybe NSString format, not NSDictionary. so you need convert it to NSDictionary before use. Try this code

```
    NSString *fizzstudentjson = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"fizzstudentjson"];

    NSData *data = [fizzstudentjson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSString *city = dictionary[@"city"];
```

Comment: id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"gender" : @"Male",
    @"city" : @"chenna",
    @"instituteName" : @"srm",
    @"profileImage" : @"ProfileImage",
    @"dob" : @"DOB",
    @"emailAddress" : @"saxasx",
    @"isStudent" : @"true",
    @"studentIdValidity" : @"Month2Year5",
    @"studentIdImage" : @"IDImage",
    @"name" : @"xasx",
    @"phoneNumber" : @"9092256227"
    };

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionary forKey:@"fizzstudentjson"];

NSDictionary *dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"fizzstudentjson"];

NSLog(@"%@",dic);

NSString *strng = [dic valueForKey:@"city"];
NSLog(@"%@",strong);
```

**Result:chenna**

Comment: did you save your dictionary data in userDefaluts

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionary forKey:@"fizzstudentjson"];

Comment: yeah I did it . Actually Saved I am accessing in different viewController I can see the data in log for (nslog dic) but cant able to access

Comment: what is the crash log ?

Comment: it;s not keyvaluecoding

Comment: that means you need to encoding your data when you are saving in insurer default and decode when you read

Comment: this is recommended way to save dic/array type data save in nsuserdefalut.

Comment: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7fb45da87de0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key city.'

Comment: but in you case you can save you dictionary in .plist

Comment: i think it will better for you